# Reference JSON object field using .map() where field name contains spaces

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

I'm using .map() to copy object fields from one JSON List to another, my issue is that the starting list I need to move the values from has spaces in the field names.

For fields with no spaces the following is working:

```
$scope.dataList = results.data.map(el => ({
     IdApplication: el.ApplicationReference,
     AccNo: el.AccountNumber
}))
```

The starting JSON however is taken directly from a CSV the user selects, and sadly the client won't change how they name their columns. So I need to map a JSON field called 'Application Reference'.

I've tried enclosing the field name in '' but this gives an identifier expected error on the first opening ' .

Bracket notation also doesn't work:

```
$scope.dataList = results.data.map(el => ({
    IdApplication: el.['Application Reference'],
    AccNo: el.AccountNumber
}))
```

This also gives an error of identifier expected on the opening [.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said bracket notation doesn't work but your example doesn't show usage of bracket notation.

The correct usage would be:

```
$scope.dataList = results.data.map(el => ({
    IdApplication: el['Application Reference'],
    AccNo: el['Account Number']
}))
```

P.S. It's considered good practice to use camelCase for JSON properties
https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml#Property_Name_Format

Comment: I forgot to update the second section of code, i've updated it now, and can see that I was doing it wrong, I was leaving the period in after "el" then doing the bracket notation. e.g. el.['Application Reference']

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
$scope.dataList = results.data.map(el => {
    IdApplication: el['Application Reference'],
    AccNo: el['Account Number']
})
```